# Getting started with npgsql, Entity Framework and postgis

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, postgis, npgsql

I'm trying to get started with npgsql, particularly the PostGIS support, but am struggling to find documentation or examples online.

I'm working with C# ASP.NET and ideally I would like to use Entity Framework style GIS queries. Something like this pseudocode:

```
var pointsInPolygon = db.points.Where(i => polygon.Contains(i.point));

var pointsInRadius = db.points.Where(i => CreateCircle(point, radius).Contains(i.point));
```

Is this kind of functionality possible with a syntax like I have posted above? If not could you please indicate how best to go about achieving it?

**Edit:** For example, how could I utilise an ST_Within query in the context of the entity framework.

Comment: Have you read something about EntityFramework? Did you try something? At least this [tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/

Comment: @hazevich yes I do know a bit about the entity framework and have successfully used it in my project for non-GIS related functionality. My question was more regarding the specific entity framework functionality enabled by npgsql.

Comment: @d1ll1nger thanks, this is the kind of thing I'm talking about. I know that geometry exercises exist but do not know if/how I can use them in an entity style way. e.g. Is ST_Within exposed by npgsql somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Npgsql does support PostGIS well, the Entity Framework 6 driver does not yet map DbGeography/DbGeometry etc. to PostGIS. See the following issue: https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/issues/18

Comment: Thanks Shay, much appreciated.